# Delphi Function that takes Integer and returns a not-so-easily decoded Integer

Tags: algorithm, delphi, pascal

Can anyone share what are some common Delphi examples of a function that takes a number
and returns a number that is not so obvious?

For example :

```
function GetNumber(const aSeed: Integer): Integer;
begin
  Result := ((aSeed+5) * aSeed) + 15;
end;
```

So let's say the user knows that sending `aSeed` = 21 gives 561
and `aSeed` = 2, gives 29
and so on...

is there a function that makes it *hard* to reverse engineer the code,
even if one can generate a large number sets of Seed/Result ?
(hard : I do not mean impossible, just need to be non-trivial)

Preferably a function that does not allow in function result exceeding the
Integer result as well.

In any case, if you are not sure whether it's hard/impossible to reverse,
do feel free to share what you have.

some other requirements:

- the same input always results in the same output; cannot have Random output
- the same output regardless of platform: windows/android/mac/ios
- won't result in some extraordinary big number (fit in Integer)

Comment: You are asking about a hash.

Comment: @RonMaupin I don't think the OP want a hash. A hash is not a reversible process. What he want is obfuscation or encryption.

Comment: For which kind of people should the reverse engineering be non trivial? What is the use case? Do you want to store the obfuscated number in a database and later get it back and don't want in the mean time that someone understand what you wrote in the database? Or do you can to send the number to another system which must get the original back? If you explain what you want to do, you'll get better advice...

Comment: There are a lot of solution in cryptography world.They usually use a key to encrypt and another or the same key to decrypt. There are symmetric and asymmetric encryption with public key or not. Really to much options to explain everything here, specifically if we don't know the real problem you have.

Comment: I'm try to get a non-random number based on a ID (ID is too obvious for my use).  I don't need to restore the result back to the original ID, but I just don't want people to know how I got the resulting Number (as much as possible).  Not looking for a hash in this case.

Comment: Do you also require that the output is never the same as a previous output? Even if the input would be the same. To prevent exceeding a range, you can use modulo (`mod` operator).

Comment: @TomBrunberg The output should be the same if the input is the same. (I don't need it random). so each input must produce a certain number, so that I can reproduce the output in future as I don't wish to store the output. oh, and the output result should be the same regardless of win32,win64, mac64 and so on.

Comment: I belive that you are looking for [Pseudorandom generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_generator) algorithm that allows generating randomlike output from a specific input.

Comment: As for making it hard to reverse engineer. You should start using much bigger numbers than just integers. Clever cracker could probably figure out what type of algorithm you are using in a manner of hours. Well it depends on how many known uncrypted and encrypted value pars he knows about. There is a reason why in modern cryptography encryption is done on blocks of data with the size of 256 bits or larger. ...

Comment: ... No to mention the use of progressive encoding, meaning that you don't decrypt all blocks of data using same key but instead all subsequent blocks are decrypted using key that is generated from decrypted data from previous block. This forces possible cracker to decrpyt all data before he can test if the encryption key he provided is correct or not and thus makes cracking of such encryption much longer process.

Comment: @SilverWarior Why use a PRNG instead of a hash? What the OP describes corresponds exactly to a hash. Besides a PRNG is not a function that takes a value and produces a value. It's a function that takes a value (the [seed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed)) and produces a *sequence* of values.

Comment: @Olivier Actually PRNG **is** a function that takes a value to produce another value. The reason why it can produce a sequence of multiple values is that every time it produces the value it also changes its seed value.

Comment: @Olivier As for your insistence on OP using a hash algorithm. The only hash algorithm that fits the OP requirements would be CRC32. In fact if we look closely on how hashing algorithms work you will notice that they actually call PRNG-like function for each cycle whilst providing the seed value for each cycle. And in order for them to work properly initial seed value must always be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a hash is a very good way to achieve what you want. Here is an example that takes an integer, converts it to a string, appends it to a [salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)), computes the MD5 and returns the integer corresponding to the first 4 bytes:

```
uses
  System.Hash;

function GetHash(const s: string): TBytes;
var
  MD5: THashMD5;
begin
  MD5 := THashMD5.Create;
  MD5.Update(TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s));
  Result := MD5.HashAsBytes;
end;

function GetNumber(Input: Integer): Integer;
var
  Hash: TBytes;
  p: ^Integer;
begin
  Hash := GetHash('secret' + IntToStr(Input));
  P := @Hash[0];
  Result := Abs(P^);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(GetNumber(1))); // 996659739
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(GetNumber(2))); // 939216101
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(GetNumber(3))); // 175456750
end;
```

Comment: thanks for this example. Much appreciated. If anyone would be kind enough to enlighten me, how do the 2 lines P := @Hash[0];   Result := Abs(P^);  how does this give the integer of the first 4 bytes? Don't get me wrong I'm not doubting the answer, just that I'm not expert enough to read this code.

Comment: @PeterJones `P` holds a pointer to an integer. `@Hash[0]` is the address of the beginning of the hash array. By assigning that address to `P` and dereferencing `P`, you get the integer that is stored at the begininng of the array. Check [this](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Pointers_and_Pointer_Types_(Delphi)) out for more details.